# Error While Reading Web Server Content of URL

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am developing a Window Application using C#.NET in Window 7. The application reads web server content from a URL. I get the following exception when I try to do that:

Error: The format of uri Could not be determing having System.UriFormatException.

This is my code:

```
StreamReader instream; 
WebRequest webrequest; 
WebResponse webresponse;
webrequest = WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
webresponse = webrequest.GetResponse();
instream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream());
textBox2.Text = instream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: You need to output `textBox1.Text` and paste it into the question. Chances are, your Uri string is malformed, or missing a protocol (that's where my money is).

Comment: Wheather use textBox or directy type in it doesnt matter. Problem Remains the same.

Comment: But *what* are you using for your input string? Paste in what you're trying to pass to `WebRequest.Create`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(textBox1.Text);    
webrequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri );
```

Comment: If he's getting a UriFormatException from his string, creating a Uri outside of the `Create` method with the same string is not going to fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your input string. It is likely missing the protocol (`http`, `https`, `ftp`, etc) or is malformed in some other way.

Comment: I have flagged your comment as rude. A `UriFormatException` implies that there is a problem with the input string. My answer makes logical sense based on the reported problem. Yours does not. If that offends you, I am sorry, but if we're trying to give gaurav00500 an answer to his question, I'm working to achieve that goal. Your solution won't work if the input string is bad. And so I downvoted it because it's wrong. That's how downvoting is supposed to work.